# Java 8 Streams taking the sum of String line

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can i find sum of all integers in this line using Stream ?

```
String line = "Test 15 lqlq 35 bad 99999 guess 34";

List<String> lineSplitted = Arrays.stream(line.split(" ")).collect(Collectors.toList());
int result = 0;
try {
    result = lineSplitted.stream().filter(s -> Integer.parseInt(s)).sum();
}
catch (Exception e) {

}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: Do you know the functions you need to do? Like filter, map, reduce, collect, etc? It's easier to compose if you know the steps

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You basically need to:

1. Convert the string to array
2. Filter out non-numbers
3. Convert the number strings to number types
4. Sum them

Working example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class HelloWorld {

     public static void main(String[] args){

        String line = "Test 15 lqlq 35 bad 99999 guess 34";

        int sum = Arrays
            .stream(line.split(" ")) // Convert to an array
            .filter((s) -> s.matches("\\d+"))  // Only select the numbers
            .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt)  // Convert to Integers
            .sum(); // Sum

        System.out.println(sum);
     }
}
```

Comment: The best so far :)

Comment: To avoid recompiling the pattern for each substring, you should use `Pattern.compile("\\d+").asPredicate()`

Answer (score 5):

How about splitting the result by every non-digit:

```
long sum = Pattern.compile("\\D+").splitAsStream(line)
                  .filter(s -> !s.isEmpty())
                  .mapToLong(Long::parseLong).sum()
```

Answer (score 3):

There's one more way, but requires jdk-9: use [`Scanner.findAll()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#findAll-java.lang.String-)

```
String line = "Test 15 lqlq 35 bad 99999 guess 34";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(line);
long result = scanner.findAll(Pattern.compile("\\d+"))
          .map(MatchResult::group)).mapToLong(Long::parseLong).sum();
System.out.println(result);
```